# How To Fetch Date type attribute from core data in swift?

Tags: objective-c, swift

In My Notes Application I Want to Add A Option Of Task Expiry Date or Target Date for That I Save Date From `UIDatePicker` in `Coredata`, But Now How I Fetch It?? I Want to fetch It And Store It In Label..... Please Give Me Answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you can read out values from CoreData:

// context is your NSManagedObjectContext

```
var fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "YourEntity")
myData = context!.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: nil) as [YourCoreDataClass]
```

So in myData there is an Array of Objects - if there is only 1 object stores, check out with:

```
if(myData.count > 0) {
   myLabel.text = myData.last!.property //(the property here for the last entry)
}
```

You could also you a predicate, to filter your Objects (like for a specific value)

```
let myPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "id = %@", anyValue)
fetchRequest.predicate = myPredicate
```

And read more here:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObjectContext_Class/index.html